# SQL How to check if field value is >0 (case when)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to do an `aggregation` with two fields but only if the value of one field is not 0.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (CC90_StatisticQueueData.NBR_OF_CONVERSATIONS)>0 
    THEN (CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION / CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION) 
FROM
    CC90_StatisticQueueData
```

I always receive `**ERROR**`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

and don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing an `END`

Comment: And perhaps an `ELSE`?

Comment: And `CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION / CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION` should probably be `SUM_WAITING_DURATION / NBR_OF_CONVERSATIONS` :-)

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger ... I always overlook the little things.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `END` Keyword in `CASE` Statement :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (CC90_StatisticQueueData.NBR_OF_CONVERSATIONS)>0 
  THEN (CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION /   
  CC90_StatisticQueueData.SUM_WAITING_DURATION) END
FROM CC90_StatisticQueueData
```