# syntax error at or near "as"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is an error I got:
*syntax error at or near "as"*

```
CASE WHEN ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN round(sum(d.spcl_prc_grs_sls_amt::double precision / f.exch_rate)::numeric, 2) as BOP_gr_sales_dol
```

Not really understand why. So need your help

Comment: Don't be lazy. Remove some stuff and see if the problem remains. If it does, remove more, and if not find take a closer look at what you've just removed.

Comment: CASE WHEN needs an END, there does not appear to be one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL How to check if field value is >0 (case when)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588685/sql-how-to-check-if-field-value-is-0-case-when). The answer is exactly the same, the question worded differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing your `END` portion of the `CASE` statement.

```
CASE WHEN ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN 
round(sum(d.spcl_prc_grs_sls_amt::double precision / f.exch_rate)::numeric, 2) as BOP_gr_sales_dol
```

Should be...

```
CASE WHEN ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN 
round(sum(d.spcl_prc_grs_sls_amt::double precision / f.exch_rate)::numeric, 2) END as BOP_gr_sales_dol
```